# sqlite3 query with optional character

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables:

- **table1** has a column named **paths1** that contains paths in the format of dir/file or /dir/file
- **table2** has a column named **paths2** that also contains paths in the format of dir/file or /dir/file

Duplicate paths can be found in both tables (the unique constraint is on another column).
I try to find if there are paths in **table1.paths1** that don't exist in **table2.paths2**.
My problem is the '/' that is sometimes exists before the path (like in the case /dir/file).

To do it I use:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT paths1
FROM table1
WHERE '/'||paths1 NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT paths2 FROM table2));
```

How can I make the '/' optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TRIM`, and remove the leading/trailing path separators from the paths in both tables, should they exist.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE TRIM(t1.paths1, '/') = TRIM(t2.paths2, '/'));
```